# ¿Expresión regular que sólo permita números mayores a 16 bits?

Tags: regex

Bueno estoy tratando de hacer una expresión regular que sólo me permita números mayores de 16 bits (en binario).

Es decir que la expresión regular permita números mayores de `1111 1111 1111 1111` es decir `>= 1 0000 0000 0000 0000`

La expresión que tengo es la siguiente:

> (1)* (1|0)* (0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)

Si alguien me puede ayudar a validar esto, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión regular está bien. Recomiendo sólo considerar los números que empiecen con el dígito más significativo en 1. De esta forma, se consideran inválidos los números que empiecen con 0 a la izquierda (lo que no aporta al número).

Recomiendo usar clausura positiva (el `+`) para asegurarse que haya al menos un uno.

Y mucho cuidado con los **espacios**, ya que la expresión regular que mostrás tiene el problema de que fuerza a que existan espacios en el número.

Quedaría así:

`(1)+(1|0)*(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)`

Dependiendo de dónde se ejecute esta expresión regular (si es en un lenguaje como Javascript ó en una herramienta como un VisualStudio Code ó un Notepad++) van a tener extensiones a la sintaxis para poder expresar esos 16 dígitos de otra forma.

Por ejemplo, en Javascript puede escribirse exactamente la misma expresión regular así:

`(1)+(1|0)*(0|1){16}`

Lo cual es claramente mucho más conciso.

Comment: Excelente! había pensado que me hacia falta el caso base en donde al menos tendría que haber un 1 como dígito mas grande, pero no estaba seguro. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No tengo conocimientos avanzados de base binaria, pero con lo basico que se; no se supone que todo numero binario que empiece por 1 es un numero negativo?

Comment: @CristianS9 no no son negativos

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular: `1[10]{16,}`. A mi juicio, más sencilla.

**Explicada:**

```
1     # Un '1' literal
[10]  # Esto representa un caracter que puede ser 1 o 0
{16,} # Repetido 16 o más veces
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UPVXI9/1/)**

---

**Importante:**

Tanto esta solución como la solución aceptada encontrarían el número `10000000000000000` dentro de `12310000000000000000321`

Lo cual puede no ser correcto para tu caso ya que ese sería un número decimal.

Si necesitases restringir este caso, puedes hacerlo con esta expresión regular:

**A) Para expresiones regulares compatibles con PCRE (como php, perl, python,...)**

`(?<!\d)1[10]{16,}(?!\d)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WXmhn4/1/)**

También se podría usar la opción B para estos lenguajes, es sólo que la opción A es más corta.

**B) Para expresiones regulares NO compatibles con PCRE, que no soporten lookbehind (como javascript)**

`(?:^|[^\d\n])(1[10]{16,}(?!\d))`

En este caso miraremos el primer grupo de captura.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW6F1Q/2/)**